# How can I avoid "borrow of moved value" when having to later unit test values?

Tags: rust, move, ownership

This is in a unit test:

```
let myobj = Obj::new();
let myvec:Vec<Obj> = obj_list.insert(&[myobj])?;

control = obj_list.get(myvec[0]);    
assert_eq!(control.id, myobj.id);
```

rustc complains about `myobj` already having been moved in the `insert` line (I understand that) when I try to access `myobj.id` in the assert.

However, how can I then test for equality? `insert` seems to require ownership...

Comment: `assert_eq!(myvec[0].id, myvec[0].id)`? The problem is the object is actually being *moved*. This isn't a formality of the borrow checker, `myobj` and the element of `myvec` are different objects in different places in memory that just happen to (at this moment) store the same information.

Comment: You want to test something that Rust doesn't allow. What's the point? Did you mean to compare to (or insert) clone()?

Comment: What type is `obj_list` even supposed to be, [`Vec::insert`](https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/vec/struct.Vec.html#method.insert) doesn't return anything and takes an index and an element not a reference to a slice or an array. Your example doesn't make sense to me at all.

Comment: I bet the issue is the baggage coming from other langs. Up to now it has been customary for me to test that I'd add an object to a custom list (`obj_list` is a database, not just a vector), that I then later can retrieve it and check it's actually there and hasn't lost properties. That'd be the point. Now maybe it's not rust-y to do that, or my thinking is a bit overkill in any case.

Comment: Important EDIT: I really apologize, I forgot to actually put the `get` call in the question. The idea thus is to insert an object into the database, then get it, and compare it's the same...

Comment: What's the signature of `insert()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should clone it instead of moving it:

```
let myobj = Obj::new();
let myvec:Vec<Obj> = obj_list.insert(&[myobj.clone()])?;

control = obj_list.get(myvec[0]);    
assert_eq!(control.id, myobj.id);
```

Make sure `Obj` implements the `Clone` trait

Comment: This actually seems to work for my case! in fact the object in question implements the `Clone` trait.